# Copying database error in android?

Tags: android

I am using my own SQLite database in android application.That is working fine on android 2.3 and above but the versions below android2.3 it not working giving error

I have attached my log file here

```
02-22 03:45:58.685: W/ResourceType(475): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
02-22 03:45:58.685: D/AndroidRuntime(475): Shutting down VM
02-22 03:45:58.685: W/dalvikvm(475): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-22 03:45:58.685: E/AndroidRuntime(475): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nframes.quotestore/com.nframes.quotestore.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2454)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.nframes.quotestore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  ... 11 more
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:171)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  ... 21 more
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020000
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1710)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1799)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:282)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  ... 25 more
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:391)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1702)
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  ... 29 more
02-22 03:45:58.811: I/dalvikvm(475): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-22 03:45:58.811: E/dalvikvm(475): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: You seem to have a layout problem. Try formatting the output a little

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root of your cause is"

> `FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png`

Are you positive that the file is there?

Perhaps it could be something to do with being in the `hdpi` folder. Try creating a new drawable folder (if it's not already in your resources) and putting your graphics there to check if it works.

You'll just have to be careful that it won't effect your app, if you are coding for different screen sizes.